# Does anyone use ICEpush on production server under heavy load?

Tags: java, icefaces, reverse-ajax

ICEpush is still in alpha version, so I am curious if it is appropriate to use in web application on tomcat or tc server with many clients. How many users can be serviced by this technology with small delay? I'm curious what is delay under 100, 1000 and 10000 clients.

What else Java library for reverse AJAX is worth to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Purely for the fact that if it is software in 'Alpha' state, I would suggest against it and I would be surprised if anyone admitted using it in a production environment.

If you are just trying to find out what load it can handle, then you could easily find out by writing a test case to exercise the code and run it locally. This advice of course doesn't address network latency nor horizontal scalability.